# Computing the outer product of two variables in xarray Dataset

Tags: python, dataframe, python-xarray

I would like to compute the outer product of two variables along a shared dimension within an [`xarray.Dataset`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/data-structures.html#dataset).

Specifically: Say I have an xarray dataset of the following form:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

ts = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
indices = range(10)
vecs1 = np.random.rand(len(ts), 10)
vecs2 = np.random.rand(len(ts), 10)

ds = xr.Dataset({'vec1': (['time', 'i1'], vecs1),
                 'vec2': (['time', 'i1'], vecs2)},
                coords={'time': ts,
                        'i1': indices,
                        'i2': indices})
```

In this dataset there is a time dimension with 100 time steps, an index `i1 = 0, 1, ..., 9` (`i2` is identical and will become relevant in a second) and variables `vec1` and `vec2` depending on these dimensions. The dataset looks like this:

```
>>> ds
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (i1: 10, i2: 10, time: 100)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) float64 0.0 0.0101 0.0202 0.0303 0.0404 0.05051 0.06061 ...
  * i1       (i1) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  * i2       (i2) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Data variables:
    vec1     (time, i1) float64 0.2531 0.9019 0.2351 0.3897 0.8144 0.9502 ...
    vec2     (time, i1) float64 0.4962 0.05394 0.1622 0.6937 0.6703 0.5646 ...
```

Now I would like to compute, at each point in time, the [outer product](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) of `vec1` and `vec2` with respect to the index `i1`, which is the matrix `outer[i1,i2] = vec1[i1] * vec2[i2]`.

Using Numpy, this can be calculated as follows:

```
v1 = ds['vec1'].values
v2 = ds['vec2'].values

# Compute the outer product along the last axis, i.e., separately for each time step,
# giving outer[:, i1, i2] == vec1[:, i1] * vec2[:, i2] for all i1, i2.
outer = np.einsum("...i,...j->...ij", v1, v2)
# Now outer.shape == (100, 10, 10)

result = ds.merge({'outer': (['time', 'i1', 'i2'], outer)})
```

Now `result['outer']` contains the desired outer product of `vec1` and `vec2` along the `i1` dimension. (The reason `i2` is used as second index is that `xarray` does not handle duplicate dimensions very well - which might be reasonable, actually, although it makes working with matrix-valued data a bit more cumversome.)

**Question:** Is there a convenient way to compute the outer product like this using functionality from xarray (which ideally should be compatible with dask arrays and able perform the calculation in parallel), without dropping back to calling numpy functions on the values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As xarray broadcasts arrays based on their dimension names, this outer product can be computed as follows:

```
In [2]: ds['vec1'] * ds['vec2'].rename(i1='i2')
```

This is equivalents the following numpy script

```
v1 = ds['vec1'].values
v2 = ds['vec2'].values    
v1[:, :, np.newaxis] * v2[:, np.newaxis]
```